# Webscraping of <dl> <dt> <dd> html tags using RVEST

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape some data using rvest from second hand car ads. However I don't manage to scrape the data which makes part of a < dl > , < dt > or < dd > html tag using the html_nodes() function.

More specifically I would like to scrape the features in the image below of the following car ad in a data frame.
https://www.autoscout24.be/nl/aanbod/mercedes-benz-slk-200-benzine-grijs-e77f7a3e-76b1-4676-88a0-b52c9574068a?cldtidx=3&cldtsrc=listPage

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUbf0.png)

Can anyone help me out please?

Thank you!
Arne

Comment: please add your code

Comment: Hi Arne. Welcome to SO. Please share some of your code and show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: See answer below :) would you mind having a look?

Answer (score 0):

This (and several other combinations - trial and error) I already tried. I would like to have a dataframe where the < dt > tag is the key and the < dd > tag is the value

```
install.packages("rvest")    
library(rvest)

autoscout_mercedes <- read_html("https://www.autoscout24.be/nl/lst/mercedes-benz?sort=standard&desc=0&ustate=N%2CU&cy=B&atype=C")

features <- autoscout_mercedes %>%    
      html_nodes("div.sc-ellipsis") %>%    
      html_nodes("a") %>%    
      html_attr("href")    

features
```

I also included a print screen of the html script.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iP2Kv.png)

Comment: Hey Arne, have you found a solution yet? :) I also want to scrape data from autoscout

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach, with this example link:

```
link <- read_html("https://www.autoscout24.de/angebote/opel-corsa-1-2-16v-klima- 
                   nsw-zv-benzin-blau-f189ee9d-b634-4bb7-8051-0e4a1f62846f? 
                   &cldtidx=1&cldtsrc=listPage&searchId=1225151069")
name <- html_text(html_nodes(link, "dl > dt"))
name
value <- html_text(html_nodes(link, "dd"))
value
test <- data.frame(name,value)

head(test)
         h2            dd
1        Zustand \nGebraucht\n
2 Fahrzeughalter         \n3\n
3          Marke      \nOpel\n
4         Modell     \nCorsa\n
5  Erstzulassung      \n2000\n
6     Außenfarbe      \nBlau\n
```